# use Contains method with array

Tags: java, arrays, contains

I'm trying to find a way to know if a string contains string pieces loaded into an array:

```
String[] phrases; 
boolean flag=false;

public class Test{
 System.out.print("Enter words separated by spaces: ");
 String[] words = in.nextLine().split(" ");
 for(String p : phrases)
  if(p.contains(words))
   flag=true;

}
```

It should work? If not, how can I search more substrings (of which I **DO NOT** know the number) in a String?

Comment: Did you try? Does it work?

Comment: It's not gonna work. words is an array, not a string.

Comment: And you need to put functionality in a method, not class directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `Arrays.asList(words).contains(p)` instead of `p.contains(words)` hope it will give you what you are trying in the code, Its just resolution for what you are trying to achieve in the code.

Also move your code in proper method as suggested by @Batty

Comment: It compiles but doesn't work. I need to return true if a certain phrase contains all the words in the array

Comment: make a check of if and else , if condition is true set the boolean value to true , if it is false make the boolean value as false and break from that point in else part. 
code- if(Arrays.asList(words).contains(p)){flag=true;}else{flag=false;break;}